# Echo text color change?

Tags: colors, echo

I am trying to change the color of the text displayed through an echo command on my website. I have tried several different methods posted on here and other forms, and they do change the color... However the variable $session->username shows as that code text on the webpage and not the actual member's user name. I am trying to change only the color of the first line ("Welcome $session->username, you are logged in."). Is there anyway to change the color without loosing the member's displayed name? Here is the code without any color changes to it:

```
if($session->logged_in){


   echo "Welcome <b>$session->username</b>, you are logged in. <br>" 
     ."[<a href=\"userinfo.php?user=$session->username\">My Account</a>] &nbsp;&nbsp;"
     ."[<a href=\"useredit.php\">Edit Account</a>] &nbsp;&nbsp;";
   if($session->isAdmin()){
       echo "[<a href=\"admin/admin.php\">Admin Center</a>] &nbsp;&nbsp;";
   }
   echo "[<a href=\"process.php\">Logout</a>]";
}
else{
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($session->logged_in){


   echo  "<div class='color'> <b>". $session->username."</b>,
 you are logged in. </div><br>" 
 ."[<a href=\"userinfo.php?user=".$session->username."\">
My Account</a>] &nbsp;&nbsp;"
 ."[<a href=\"useredit.php\">Edit Account</a>] &nbsp;&nbsp;";
  if($session->isAdmin()){
   echo "[<a href=\"admin/admin.php\">Admin Center</a>] &nbsp;&nbsp;";
 }
 echo "[<a href=\"process.php\">Logout</a>]";
}
else{
```

Comment: Just added a div tag to easily style through CSS. Note that quotes are tricky when echoing.

Comment: how would i add the welcome in front? it keeps giving me an error if I have it in front of . $session->username

Comment: What does the error say? Seems kind of weird. What code do you use now?

Comment: It says  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Welcome' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\Clanripp-gamming\Index.php on line 125

Comment: ahh, nvm got it, I was just putting in in the wrong section. Thanks for your help!